# jQuery selector to target elements with possible text content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want a click event to fire on any element with class 'editable' that has, or can have (or traditionally has) text content: a, li, h1, h2, h3, p.. but not video, img and other elements that don't directly contain text.

Is there a way to do this without referring to specific html elements? or.. how would I exclude specific element types from the following:

```
$(".editable").click(function(event) {
   alert("edit text!");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if there is a pre-defined selector that will choose only these elements.
as for execlusion you can use the not() function:

```
$(".editable").not("video").not("img")
 .click(function(event) {
   alert("edit text!");
});
```

Here's the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/not/

EDIT: it'll probably be more efficient to call the function once thus:

```
$(".editable").not("video,img")
 .click(function(event) {
   alert("edit text!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude using the not selector or function.

**Selector**

```
$('.editable:not(video, img)').click(function(e){

});
```

**Function**

```
$('.editable').not('video, img').click(function(e){

});
```

**[JSFiddle with Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cYgHt/)**